# Xcode 8 beta 6: Cannot validate sticker pack archive

Tags: ios, xcode8

I made a sticker pack archive and cannot get it to validate.  I understand that Xcode 8 beta 6 cannot submit at this time, but can it validate for builds destined for TestFlight?  I get this error:

```
Permissions failure: Your account does not have permission to create iOS Distribution certificates
```

I am listed as a "Member" within my organization.

Comment: You must be at least Admin to create distribution certificates

Comment: @azimov Is there a way for me to get a build up for distribution with TestFlight without having this status?

Comment: I get this error when trying to validate/publish an archive with XCode 8 and Xcode 7.3.1.  This seems like an bug or a mislabeled exception as my company already has iOS Distribution certificates, I shouldn't have to create a new one just to validate/publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to ask responsible member of an organization, you work in, for at least **Team agent** privileges.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html
[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

[image]
[developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH16-SW14)

[image]

Or at least to ask team agent or team admin for preparing proper *Certificate with private key* for you.