# Unable to fix signing issue Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to test my unity game on different iOS device using Xcode 7.3.1. Previously, I connect my iPhone 6 on mac and test the game successfully with free apple account(that has limited privilege). 
Now I want to test that game on different device and later want to upload to app store. So I asked my client for apple id that has role "agent". I add apple id on Xcode and try to run the project with iPhone 6 connected. I got the error message saying-

**"Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate"
"You have a valid iOS Distribution certificate in the Member Center, but it is not installed locally. If your signing identity is installed on another Mac, you can export a developer profile on that Mac and import it on this Mac. You can also reset your current certificate."**

Then I click on reset button to reset current certificate. And try to run the project again. Again I got the error message saying-

**Unable to fix   signing issue.
Xcode failed to resolve the issue. Check your code signing settings; ensure you have a matching signing certificate and provisioning profile installed; and try again.**

I restarted Xcode many times but got the same error. Screenshot of my account details looks like below .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km7nu.png)

Comment: May Be You have again Login in Your Developer Account in Xcode.

Comment: Go to xcode prefference
click on account and add apple id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough, to login and download Developer profiles only.

You need that Certificate physically and signed in your mac as well.

Ak your client to export **Signing identities and Provisioning Profiles**.
This you will be able to import to you Xcode and Keychain in one step.

This process will help you handle private keys as well, as they are necessary if signing App using Developer/Distribution Certificate.

**1)** Your client has to **export Identities and profiles**:

[image]

**2)** **He/She** can **send** you them by **e-mail**:

[image]

[image]

**3)** You can **import them all** in one.

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013306-CH8-SW1

---

When **recreation of Certificates and Provisioning Profiles** is needed:
Make sure you have appropriate privileges - you have to be team agent or admin:

**1) Login** to https://developer.apple.com with your developer credentials.

**2)** Go to **Certificates, IDs & Profiles**

[image]

**3)** Go to **Certificates** and **remove the old** one. Then **Add new**:

[image]

**4)** This is few step process, that requires you to create Certificate signing request. Just follow steps that are stated there. The last action in this step will be installing that Certificates - when ready, just click on it/them and they seamlessly get to your Keychain.

**5)** When finished with Certificates, open **Profiles**, find those marked with yellow triangle and **edit** them. Check the new certificate (and devices if you are **creating** Development profile as well). I personally prefer creating brand new profiles, as it it'll be easier to recognise older ones and new ones in Build settings later.

[image]

[image]

**6)** You now have to **update your Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts section** and Xcode does this for you.

[image]

**7)** **Last step - update Build settings** in your projects according to your new profiles. You should be ready to validate you project now.

Comment: Yes, in this case it would be better, before any import to delete that ID first. Do not make any changes in project certs /profiles settings, as it may collide  later with what Xcode will expect after import.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. Now I will ask for "signing identities and provisioning profile". As I had mention in question , after adding client apple id on Xcode , and build a project , I got a error first error mentioned in above question..**Then I click on reset button to reset current certificate**. **Does it make any effect on client project that had been uploaded in app store**   ....When I log into apple developer site with client apple id , Under  _iOS Provisioning Profiles section _ **status of all provisioning profile is invalid(Managed by Xcode).**

Comment: This will definitely not affect an App in the app store. Don't worry. But your client now has to create another Cert and Profiles but it's usual event, I did it multiple times till I finally learned how to handle them. Invalid status of other profiles in dev account only means that developers will need to update them to be able deploying updates

Comment: If this helped, please make appropriate action (vote, accept, as you fell fine with). Happy development.

Comment: The solution you mentioned works well if I had not reset the current certificate. But unfortunately, I reset the current certificate, and new error occurred saying .. **Unable to fix signing issue. Xcode failed to resolve the issue. Check your code signing settings; ensure you have a matching signing certificate and provisioning profile installed; and try again.** How should I get out of this error?

Comment: @ero I mistakenly made an answer instead the comment. You wrote you need step by step guide. My question before that: Have you privileges for managing certificates? Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39353127/661022, and let me know.

Comment: Currently I am using the client's **Team Agent** Account that have full privilege.

Comment: @ero I did my best to provide you with steps how to do it. Answer updated.